# How to rollback to older release in azure release pipeline which uses Docker-compose

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Since I am building the image and pushing to the Azure container registry(so far it's ok.) the problem for me starting after this.

Let's say I build several images with the build tag. such as api-image:23, api-image:24, api-image:25 and so on.

Question comes here: I'm running with the tag 25(also latest) in production server then I want to rollback to api-image:23(Using azure release pipeline history). My docker-compose file also has this **image: api-image** value. It's going to get **'latest'** image.
How can I get those image tags as dynamically in my compose file? As you know, Azure Devops release pipelines has a release history. Let's say I want to rollback to ex-release. How my docker-compose file knows which version I want to rollback to? If I leave the tag empty its going to get a latest tag. But my ex-release builded with api-image:23.

Also, this image already in my azure registry so I don't need to rebuild the whole project again right? I should be using it without rebuilding the app?

ps. my hosts are debian 11 on-premise.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: xx.azurecr.io/nginx
    container_name: mars_proxy
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: reverse-proxy/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
  slider:
    image: xx.azurecr.io/mars-slider
    container_name: slider
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Mars.Slider/Presentation/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:5100"
    restart: always
```

My Azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
  - develop
 
steps:
  - task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: "Container registry login"
    inputs: 
      containerregistrytype: "Azure Container Registry"
      #azureSubscription = Azure resource manager service connection name 
      azureSubscription: "subname"
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"xx.azurecr.io", "id" : ""}'
      dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
      additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
      action: 'Build services'

  - task: DockerCompose@0
    inputs: 
      containerregistrytype: "Azure Container Registry"
      azureSubscription: "subname"
      azureContainerRegistry: '{"loginServer":"xx.azurecr.io", "id" : ""}'
      dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'
      additionalImageTags: $(Build.BuildId)
      action: 'Push services'
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) to fill in environment-variable values in many places in a Compose file.  This includes the `image:`.  So if you're able to provide the image tag as an environment variable:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: xx.azurecr.io/nginx:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}  # <--
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
  slider:
    image: xx.azurecr.io/mars-slider:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}  # <--
    ports:
      - "8081:5100"
    restart: always
```

Then you can roll back just by providing the older value for the tag:

```bash
IMAGE_TAG=23 docker-compose up -d
```

You can similarly use this technique to upgrade to a known "current" version if other builds are ongoing, and to minimize the risk of the system having an incorrect "latest" version.  If you're supplying the tag explicitly like this then you do not need to manually `docker-compose pull` the rebuilt images; Docker will fetch them automatically if they're not present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify tag number for example: `$(build.buildNumber)` when building/pushing the image:

```yaml
#build_pipeline.yml
jobs:
- job: Job_1
...
  - task: DockerCompose@0
    displayName: Build services
    inputs:
...
      dockerComposeFile: docker-compose.yml
      action: Build services
      additionalImageTags: $(build.buildNumber)
      dockerComposeCommand: up
```

Now, make sure to add the same tag in your release pipeline for deployment.

If you want to deploy old release, just list previous releases:

[image]

Select One, and Hit >> Deploy

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping, can you also share your release pipeline steps. So I can see clearly where should I exactly insert the $(build.buildNumber).

Comment: Also, what artifact do you choosing in release pipeline? From azure registry images? or azure project repo?

Comment: @godzkaya private Azure Container Registry, your azure build pipeline should consist of two stages : (Build then Push)

Comment: now it's saying  [https://ibb.co/VMpYtxY](https://ibb.co/VMpYtxY) and this is my Release pipeline steps [https://ibb.co/KXTc4ky](https://ibb.co/KXTc4ky) and I selected azure container reg as artifact. Btw ofc it cannot find my dockerfiles because I select azure registry not azure repo right?

Comment: @godzkaya this is another issue, you may close this one and open another question

Comment: one more question. you said 'Now, make sure to add the same tag in your release pipeline for deployment.' can you share any example regarding this? I dont see any input to add this command in compose area https://ibb.co/KXTc4ky